# Value of $\log_e{1.2}$ correct to $7$ decimal places

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, truncation-error

My aim is to find the value of $\log_e 1.2$ correct to $7$ decimal places using the Taylor's series

$$\log_e(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$

For $7$ decimal places accuracy, the absolute error term $R_n(0.2)< 0.5×10^{-7}$

$1$. Now if I take $R_n=\frac{x^n}{n}$ where $n\ge 1$ then $n=9$ which means :

$ a. $ Only $9$ terms are sufficient or,

$b. $ Only $8$ terms are sufficient (as $n=9$ contributes to the error term).

$2$. And if I take $R_n=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, where $n\ge 0$ then $n=9$ which means:

$a.$ only $n=9$ terms are sufficient, or

$b.$ only $9$ terms are sufficient (as $n=9$ contributes to the error term so terms corresponding to $0\le n\le 8$ i.e. $9$ terms are required).

**Added**: I am completely confused in reaching the correct conclusion, but I think after **Michael Hardy's answer that $2.b$ is correct**. Kindly tell which one is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a series alternating between positive and negative terms, with the absolute values of the terms decreasing to $0,$ the error after summing the first several terms is always smaller than the absolute value of the next term. It's easy to prove that; see if you can do that.

So
\begin{align}
& 0.2 - \frac{0.2^2} 2 + \frac{0.2^3} 3 - \frac{0.2^4} 4 + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & 0.2 - 0.02 + \frac{0.008} 3 + \text{error} \\[10pt]
\text{and error} < {} &  \frac{0.2^4}{4} = \frac{0.0016} 4 = 0.0004.
\end{align}
Now keep going until the error is small enough.

Comment: ...so here $\frac{0.2^{10}}{10}=1.02(10^{-8})<0.5(10^{-7})$ . Does it mean $9$ terms are sufficient?

Comment: @Mathlover : Yes. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael Hardy. Is the process same for a positive term series like $e^x$?

Comment: @Mathlover : What I wrote does not apply to series in which all terms have the same sign. If I wanted to compute $e^4$ and had only a pen and paper, I would find $e^{-4}$ by using the power series and then take a reciprocal. With $e^4$ directly, the error term will go to $0$ far more slowly.